# Which Visual Studio to target broadest array of Windows machines?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I develop a large open source C++ program.  On Windows, we typically build our downloadable releases with Visual Studio Express.  In the past, I've tried to use an old version of Windows and an old version of Visual Studio to try to maintain compatibility with as many user's machines as possible -- and to also keep the development environment as accessible as possible to contributors.

We do use some C++11.  We currently use VS 2010 Express on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 (64 bit).  We target Win32.  We do not use any .Net stuff.

Unfortunately, as built, our program crashes on Windows 8.1 -- it starts to load, but crashes with a non helpful error message 'myprogram.exe Has stopped working.'  I can't yet tell if this 'should work', or if it is a bug in our program that only Win8 triggers (it works fine on earlier Windows as well as OSX and Linux).

I'm finding it very difficult to figure out the target compatibility matrix for Windows & Visual Studio.  Assume that all versions of Windows and Visual Studio are available.

So, what version of Visual Studio and/or Windows SDK 'should work' to produce a single executable that will work on the widest range of Windows versions?

Or, what is the minimum number of builds (and how) we could do to target the widest array of Windows versions?

Alternatively, would MinGW provide a substantially better result for us?  If so, which version & platform should we use?

We currently only build 32-bit versions, but how would going 64-bit change this discussion?

Comment: This is pretty broad.  Have you tried debugging the program on Windows 8.1?  Do you have all of the necessary redistributables installed?  The only real question is if you need to support XP or not.

Comment: I've installed all the required redistributables.  I haven't debugged it yet because it will require installing Visual Studio on the Win 8.1 machine -- and I was specifically trying to target a machine without a bunch of dev tools installed.  If I can drop XP, what does that do for the conversation?

Comment: @user52485 I think it's time for you to consider development on a machine with multiple VM's with the operating systems you plan to support.  Your situation is exactly why programs such as VMWare exist.  If you had such a program, all you would need to do is install the OS in the VM, the compiler tools, and test.

Comment: You can use windbg or the remote debugger without installing all of Visual Studio.  As far as I know all versions of Visual Studio allow for XP compatibility, but the most recent version (2012, 2013) do so by using an older set of headers for the XP compatible toolchain.  You would need to determine if your application would build that way or not.

Comment: I concur with @RetiredNinja and cannot street enough how having a good fundamental working knowledge of WinDbg can be an absolute lifesaver. Yes, its UI is dreadful, but its *incredibly* powerful. Can do nothing but good to learn more about.

Comment: Don't worry, I do use a VM.  My main development machine is a Mac with a bunch of VirtualBox VM's.  However, it is still highly desirable to limit the combinations that you have to work with.

Comment: Well, a debug build requires MSVC100D.dll -- that isn't redistributable.  So, you end up putting VS 2010 on the machine anyway.  Debugging into it now, it looks like an OpenGL problem...